# Check columns for two seperate rows and return true if identical

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering if it's possible to do a check on the mysql side (from a query) to see if for two different unique ids some of the columns match. Already solved it in php but i would like to simplify it if possible.

Structure say is this

```
product | attribute_1 | attribute_2 | attribute_3
-------------------------------------------------
1         10             20            30
2         10             20            31
3         10             20            30
```

So that it will return true for `1-3` and false for `1-2` or `1-3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this as well:

```
select exists (
 select 1 from TableName t1, TableName t2
 where 
 t1.`Attribute_1` = t2.`Attribute_1` and
 t1.`Attribute_2` = t2.`Attribute_2` and
 t1.`Attribute_3` = t2.`Attribute_3` and
 t1.`Product` = $id1 and
 t2.`Product` = $id2
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT atribute_1, atribute_2, atribute_3, count(*) as `Count of duplicated rows`  
FROM  YOUR_TABLE group by atribute_1, atribute_2, atribute_3
```

Answer (score 1):

You may do it with:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT attribute1, attribute2, attribute3 FROM t WHERE product=$id1) 
  = 
  (SELECT attribute1, attribute2, attribute3 FROM t WHERE product=$id2)
```

-i.e. check tuples on equality. Your `$id1` and `$id2` are derived from application, for example.